# Probability question of two related variable: Law of total probability

Tags: probability

Can you help me on how to do this question please?

> On any given day, the probability of weather $A$ is $0.8$, and the chance of a person winning a race in this weather is $70\%$, but the chance of a person winning is only $30\%$ in Weather $B$. Determine the probability that the person will win on any given day.

Can anyone help plz.

Comment: Could you tell us your attempts to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Denote with $W$ the event that a person wins on any given day. By the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) we can condition on whether the weather is $A$ or $B$. This gives \begin{align}P(W)&=P(W\mid A)P(A)+P(W\mid B)P(B)\\[0.2cm]&=P(W\mid A)P(A)+P(W\mid B)\left(1-P(A)\right)\\[0.2cm]&=0.7\cdot0.8+0.3\cdot(1-0.8)=0.62\end{align} or $62\%$.